# How to generate a list in an Access Report?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-reports

I'm trying to generate a report in Microsoft Access which should make a list based on the content stored in a field called Exams in a Table named Checkup.

So far I have a report with a calculated field and a textbox with record source Exams. The calculated field uses Switch function to generate the list; here's the code:

```
=Switch([Examenes]="BHC","BHC" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Hto:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Gb:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "E:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "S:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "L:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "M:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "St:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "B:",[Examenes]="BHC, VDRL","BHC" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Hto:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Gb:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "E:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "S:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "L:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "M:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "St:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "B:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "VDRL:",[Examenes]="BHC, EGO, VDRL","BHC" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Hto:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "GB:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "E:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "S:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "L:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "M:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "St:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "B:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "VDRL:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "EGO" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Color:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Densidad:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Ph:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "SO:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Proteinas:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "CE:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "LL:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "FM:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Nitrito:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Cristales:",[Examenes]="BHC, EGH, EGO, VDRL","BHC" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Hto:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Gb:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "E:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "S:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "L:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "M:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "St:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "B:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "VDRL:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "EGO" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Color:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Densidad:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Ph:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "SO:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Proteinas:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "CE:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "LL:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "FM:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Nitrito:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Cristales:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "EGH" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Protozoarios:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Metazoarios:")
```

The code works well, however, I need to add more values to the Switch function but I get error message "The text is too long to be edited". Since this field is calculated I can't just go to the table and add more characters or make it into a memo type field (or I least I don't know how).

Is there a workaround to this issue? I've also tried putting the code to onLoad (or OnOpen) event in  the report, but haven't gotten it to work. Access gives me Compile error: Expected: list separator or )

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Switch([Examenes]="BHC","BHC" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Hto:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Gb:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "E:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "S:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "L:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "M:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "St:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "B:",[Examenes]="BHC, VDRL","BHC" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Hto:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Gb:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "E:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "S:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "L:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "M:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "St:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "B:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "VDRL:",[Examenes]="BHC, EGO, VDRL","BHC" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Hto:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "GB:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "E:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "S:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "L:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "M:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "St:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "B:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "VDRL:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "EGO" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Color:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Densidad:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Ph:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "SO:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Proteinas:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "CE
:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "LL:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "FM:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Nitrito:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Cristales:",[Examenes]="BHC, EGH, EGO, VDRL","BHC" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Hto:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Gb:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "E:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "S:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "L:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "M:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "St:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "B:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "VDRL:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "EGO" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Color:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Densidad:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Ph:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "SO:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Proteinas:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "CE:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "LL:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "FM:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Nitrito:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Cristales:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "EGH" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Protozoarios:" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Metazoarios:")
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a simple `Select ... Case` construct:

```vb
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    Const BHC   As String = "BHC" & vbCrLf & "Hto:" & vbCrLf & "Gb:" & vbCrLf & "E:" & vbCrLf & "S:" & vbCrLf & "L:" & vbCrLf & "M:" & vbCrLf & "St:" & vbCrLf & "B:"
    Const VDRL  As String = vbCrLf & "VDRL:"    
    Const EGO   As String = vbCrLf & "EGO" & vbCrLf & "Color:" & vbCrLf & "Densidad:" & vbCrLf & "Ph:" & vbCrLf & "SO:" & vbCrLf & "Proteinas:" & vbCrLf & "CE:" & vbCrLf & "LL:" & vbCrLf & "FM:" & vbCrLf & "Nitrito:" & vbCrLf & "Cristales:"
    Const EGH   As String = vbCrLf & "EGH" & vbCrLf & "Protozoarios:" & vbCrLf & "Metazoarios:"

    Dim Value   As string

    Select Case Me!Examenes.Value
        Case "BHC"
            Value = BHC
        Case "BHC, VDRL"
            Value = BHC & VDRL
        Case "BHC, EGO, VDRL"
            Value = BHC & VDRL & EGO
        Case "BHC, EGH, EGO, VDRL"
            Value = BHC & VDRL & EGO & EGH
    End Select

    ' Display result.
    Me!YourUnboundTextbox.Value = Value

End Sub
```

Comment: GREAT!!! Thanks a bunch Gustav!!! I will try your proposed solution ASAP!

Comment: Hi again @Gustav! I've been working on your recommended approach but am having problems getting my unbound textbox to display the variable. Here's the code: `Private Sub Orden_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Const EGH   As String = "EGH" & vbCrLf & "Protozoarios:" & vbCrLf & "Metazoarios:"
    Const VDRL  As String = "VDRL:"
    Dim ListOrder As String
    Select Case Me!Examenes.Value
        Case "VDRL"
            ListOrder = VDRL
        Case "EGH"
            ListOrder = EGH
    End Select
    Me!txtList.Value = ListOrder
End Sub` Thanks so much in advance for your support

Comment: Not sure what `Orden_Open` might be. Use my code, replace in the last line the name of your textbox.

Comment: Thanks again... Orden_Open is name of my report with the list. I will go at it again. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi again @Gustav . I was totally wrong with the `Orden_Open` part of my code in line 1! I was under the impression that I had to put the name of my report followed by _Open. I corrected my mistake and left it 'Report_Open'. However I'm getting a Run Time Error 2427: "You entered an expression that has no value" and highlights the row with code `Select Case Me!txtExamenes.Value`. If I delete the entire code and open the report I see txtExamenes textbox returning the value stored in the table, so I don't know why I'm getting the runtime error. Please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Also, if I make reference to the field in the table in the same row as the comment above `Select Case Me!Examenes.Value`I get Runtime error 2465: Can't find the field 'Examenes' referred to in your expression.

Comment: I've seen no `txtExamenes`, so use `Examenes` which worked in your original code.